# Edit order which has already invoiced

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, sales-order, sales, order-status

i want to do edit order with out creating new order but issue is that invoice is already created for that order.[I know that after invoice order can not be edit but i want to know that is there any hack or any hard trick available?]

Is there any other option available for me.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Editing an order is not a good idea, especially if you have other systems depending on it where it might have been exported to. Which parts do you need to change and edit?

Comment: actually i want to cancel order but issue is that invoice is already created @Anna Volkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a few options but depending on what you plan on editing it might not be wise.

1. You can go straight to the order tables in the database using your favorite mysql tool like PHPMyAdmin
2. Doing some googling there are a few extensions available like [this one](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/magento-edit-order-manager.html)

Comment: actually i want to cancel order but issue is that invoice is already created @Winston